# Click handler not triggered for textfield with editable="false"

Tags: android, onclick, appcelerator

This code has been working until one of the most recent updates to the SDK. Now it only works for iOS - and not for Android (API versions 19-23 tested).

Alloy snippet:

```
<ScrollView id="form" onClick="clickHandler" onFocus="clickHandler">
    :
    :
<View class="formRow" id="clubRow1">
    <Label id="label_club" />
    <TextField id="club1" class="club" editable="false" bubbleParent="true"></TextField>
</View>
```

Controller snippet:

```
function clickHandler(e){
    console.trace('profile.clickHandler: ' + (e.source.id || 'no id!'));
    if(e && e.source){
        :
        :
```

I use a top-level click handler (results are the same if I have the click handler on the `<TextField>`). If I remove `editable="false"` then the click handler is triggered.

I use this functionality to show the user a list of values they can select from (either from a listview with search capabilities or a simple option list if just a few values).

Is there any way I can obtain this functionality again? Is this an error in the SDK - or just me doing something awkward to obtain the functionality?

Environment:

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.12.1
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 16.0GB

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.5.0
  npm Version                 = 2.15.9

Appcelerator CLI
  Installer                   = 4.2.7
  Core Package                = 5.5.1

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.9
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.31

Titanium SDKs
  5.5.0.GA
    Version                   = 5.5.0
    Install Location          = /Users/jda/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.0.GA
    Platforms                 = android, mobileweb, iphone
    git Hash                  = 44a2e3f
    git Timestamp             = 09/13/16 12:38
    node-appc Version         = 0.2.36
```

Comment: Maybe adding "touchEnabled" on the textField would help?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @OutofOrbit. That property is `true` by default - and setting it explicitly did not change anything - unfortunately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was informed by another developer on Ti.Slack (@baharroth) that this apparently is [a known bug](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24003). Just adding it here for everybody else to find.

It could be solved by using e.g. `onTouchEnd` or `onSimpleTouch`. However, an even better solution (in my opinion) is to set `focusable="false"` and `editable="true"` for the `<TextField>` - but only for Android. For iOS it still has to just be `editable="false"`

So the best way to implement this is really like this:

In app.tss:

```
".pickList[platform=android]": {
    focusable:false,
    editable:true   
}
".pickList[platform=ios]": {
    editable:false  
}
```

And in the Alloy markup file:

```
<TextField id="country" class="pickList" bubbleParent="true"></TextField>
```

This seems to work fine (for my situation, any way).